# What math topics are most needed to become data scientist?

Tags: machine-learning

I am trying to learn data science from very different sources like Coursera, edx and many other sources. But I can not able to find any proper syllabus that what actually topics are needed. So, if anyone can please list out topics that I can follow and able to complete data science math skills.

Even if you post the name of books which can able to complete these criteria, then also it will be a great help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to the site! you can go through the following link where all of us answered the same question. You can refer to my answer where all those books are very helpful. [link](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/26449/beginner-math-book-for-machine-learning/26463#26463)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linear Algebra, Calculus, Probability and Statistics are fundamental topics.

Lots of great books out there, Khan Academy is a good resource as well:

https://www.khanacademy.org/math/linear-algebra

https://www.khanacademy.org/math/calculus-1

https://www.khanacademy.org/math/statistics-probability